# CSS and Javascript are not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

My css and Javascript are not showing when I open my file in browser via folder. My files are in the same folder which is a subfolder of subfolders

I have tried renaming files.

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>A simple calculator</title>
</head>


<script src="calc.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is your closing <head/> tag?

Comment: Please share your folder structure with us so we can see where your index.html file is compared to the other files

Comment: C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\CodingOni.github.io\bCalculator

Comment: Here is my html code <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>A simple calculator</title>
 </head>

Comment: it will not let me edit my code im sorry i am new to stack overflow

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a syntax error in your javascript file that is causing the file to fail to load? Check the Developer Console on your browser to see if there are any errors logged.

Comment: please add your html code here

Comment: Try using "../" without quotation marks to indicate that the files are located in the subfolders

Answer (score 0):

You can use ./ to indicate that the css and js files are in the same directory or to indicate the current directory. This would be relative path for the css and js files.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700" rel="stylesheet">
         <title>A simple calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="./calc.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you want to identify,where those css files and javascript files are located.That means which folders contains particular  css files and javascript files. when you integrating css files and javascript files with main html page  , set the path to particular css or javascript file from current directory.if particular files are in same level with your current working directory , initialize the path to particular directory.At the same time id you working directory and particular directory are in deferent levels , at first go to particular directory level and initialize the path.(if you want to go previous(back) directory , ' .' can be used.
ex - if you want to go back 1 level './' can be used. if you want to go back two levels of directory '../' can be used.).I hope, you got the idea. cheers !